# Captcha image not displayed when publishing website

Tags: asp.net, captcha, publishing

I'm using some captcha control implementation which I took from [here](http://www.mondor.org/captcha.aspx) and it's working fine in my localhost but the problem rises when publishing it on the server. The captcha image itself is not displayed. Of course I'm using master page and the captcha itself is under some usercontrol. 
Is there any known issue for this when publishing. What I'm I missing something here here ?
Anything to be changed in my web.config file??

Thank you guys! Any answer would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe session disabled on server.

Comment: My IIS Version is  6.0 and Session is enabled on server.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution guys. In fact although using IIS 6 in my pc, I was publishing the website on a server using IIS 7. And for IIS 7 if you want to use custom handlers you have to register them from  Handler Mappings and Add Managed Handler you can find a good article here  [Configuring Custom Http Handler in IIS 7](http://infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2007/02/configuring_custom_http_handle.html) otherwise you custom handler is not recognized and captcha image not handled properly.

then you have to make your managed handler enabled and then everything works great.

So it was an IIS issue, apparently it was not enough adding the handler in web.config file.